# Division operator resulting in large number precision

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I divide an integer by a number such as 100.00, I end up with a column with 6+ trailing zeros.

For example, when I am expecting 8600/100.00 to result in a value of 86.00, I instead get 86.000000.

I don't remember this being the case in the past -- did something change? Is there a setting in Snowflake to alter this? I know I can cast the column to a specific precision manually or use a floor function but I'd prefer not to do this for every division operation.

Comment: select round(8600/100.00);

Comment: What is it that you'd like to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select round(8600/100.00,2);
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm aware of the various workarounds but I was more wondering if there is a way to have it automatically use the least precise scale without losing accuracy. I'd prefer not to implement the workaround for every column we are dividing on.

Comment: Please read the documentation for division. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic.html#division . The result is as per their documentation for  Leading digits, scale and precision. If you want a specific one you can use round.